# How to find and replace '[' in a String?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

i am having a String "['MET', 'MISSED']". Here i want to replace "[ to [ and ]" to ]. I have used the escape sequences in my String like

```
wkJsonStr.replaceAll("\"\\[","[");
```

and

```
wkJsonStr.replaceAll("\\]\"","]");
```

but none of the above worked. In 'watch' i edited like

```
wkJsonStr.replaceAll("\"[","[");
```

and it worked. But in my Android Studio Editor this Expression is not allowed. I am getting "Unclosed character class".

I am expecting my String after replacing to be like ['MET', 'MISSED']. I want to remove the first and last quotation alone and i would like to achieve it by replaceAll method.

Comment: is `"` actually exists in your string?

Comment: So, why use a regex based replacement if you need a literal string replacement? Use `.replace("\"[", "[").replace("]\"", "]")`.

Comment: `String#replaceAll` works with regex, where `]` is part of the regex syntax.(which causes the `Unclosed character class` error message you are recieving). Instead use the plain `String` replacement method, `String#replace`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes brother

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This i have tried already and i am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: @KevinEsche You mean String.replace method?

Comment: @AnandAsir: Exactly, not `replaceAll`, but `replace` - see my comment.

Comment: Why not use: `String newString = yourString.subString(1, yourString.length()-2);`? Is there a specific reason to use a `replaceAll`? If you have more than one `[...]` element, you can split the string.

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg Yes. Because Sometimes this String will be in between of some other strings also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that string are immutable in java...

just calling the replace method will take no effect, you need to assign the return value, otherwise will get lost.

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String wkJsonStr = "\"['MET', 'MISSED']\"";
    System.out.println(wkJsonStr);
    wkJsonStr = wkJsonStr.replaceAll("\"\\[", "[").replaceAll("\\]\"", "]");
    System.out.println(wkJsonStr);
}
```

this will print.

> "['MET', 'MISSED']"
>
> ['MET', 'MISSED']

Comment: This is the perfect explanation than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`, but if you really need to use `replaceAll` then you can do:

```
wkJsonStr.replaceAll("\"\\Q[\\E","[").replaceAll("\\Q]\\E\"","]")
```

Here,

- `\"` literally denotes `"`
- The part between `\\Q` and `\\E` is literally treated., i.e,

  - `\\Q[\\E` denotes `[`
  - `\\Q]\\E` denotes `]`

Comment: Thanks.. Let me try this and tell you

Comment: Its not Working.. when i am giving wkJsonStr.indexOf("\"\\Q[\\E") its giving -1. same for wkJsonStr.indexOf("\\Q]\\E\"")..

Comment: @AnandAsir `indexOf` searches for a literal String, and not a regex. So, indexOf will not find it. But if you try to replace using it, it will work the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with *@Wiktor Stribiżew*'s comment. And you should declare your String like this:

```
String str = "\"['MET', 'MISSED']\""; // like this your editor will not give an error
str = str.replace("\"[","[");
str = str.replace("]\"","]");
textview.setText(str);
```

Comment: No I tried this and am getting Regular Expression '"\"["' is malformed.Unclosed character class.

Comment: you take single quotes??

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized that the isssue is not with the Regex character. Its the Variable which i am using. when i am replacing one by one it is not forwarding the result to the next step. So i have assigned the value to a variable and now its working.

```
String firstResult = wkJsonStr.replaceAll("\"\\[","[");
```

and

```
String result = firstResult.replaceAll("\\]\"","]");
```

is working for me. Or This step will do a trick.

```
String result= wkJsonStr.replaceAll("\"\\[","[").replaceAll("\\]\"","]");
```